# Can NAN and INFINITY be used under non-default rounding modes?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding, nan, infinity

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fenv.h>

#if _MSC_VER && ! __clang__ && ! __INTEL_COMPILER
#pragma fenv_access (on)
#else
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#endif

int main(void)
{
    float f;
    if (fesetround(RM) != 0) return 1;
    f = V;
    printf("%f\n", f);
    return 0;
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t583.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -DV=NAN -DRM=FE_TOWARDZERO && ./a.exe
nan

$ gcc t583.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -DV=INFINITY -DRM=FE_TOWARDZERO && ./a.exe
inf

$ cl t583.c /std:c11 /Za /fp:strict /DV=NAN /DRM=FE_TOWARDZERO /nologo && ./t583.exe
0.000000

$ cl t583.c /std:c11 /Za /fp:strict /DV=INFINITY /DRM=FE_TOWARDZERO /nologo && ./t583.exe
340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

GCC defines `NAN` and `INFINITY` as:

```
#define NAN           (__builtin_nanf(""))
#define INFINITY      (__builtin_inff())
```

while MSVC defines `NAN` and `INFINITY` as:

```
#define NAN           ((float)(INFINITY * 0.0F))
#define INFINITY      ((float)(_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF))
```

and `_HUGE_ENUF` as:

```
#define _HUGE_ENUF    1e+300 // _HUGE_ENUF*_HUGE_ENUF must overflow
```

So, with MSVC under `/fp:strict` AND under `FE_TOWARDZERO` and `FE_DOWNWARD`:

- the `INFINITY` evaluates to `FLT_MAX`, and
- the `NAN` evaluates to `0.0`.

Confused.

However, is it allowed at all to use `NAN` and `INFINITY` under non-default rounding modes, such as `FE_TOWARDZERO` and `FE_DOWNWARD`?

---

Reason of the question: better understanding of the C standard.

What problem is being solved: experimenting with non-default rounding modes using MSVC, trying to produce expected results.

---

UPD. Answer from Microsoft:

> Thanks for reporting this and help us improve our libraries. This issue has been fixed and will be available in a future update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it allowed at all to use `NAN` and `INFINITY` under non-default rounding modes, such as `FE_TOWARDZERO` and `FE_DOWNWARD`?

The language specification does not express any limitation on using `INFINITY`.  A conforming implementation must therefore accept it and interpret it consistently with the provisions of the language specification regardless of rounding mode.  Specifically, it

> expands to a constant expression of type `float` representing positive
> or unsigned infinity, if available; else to a positive constant of
> type `float` that overflows at translation time.

(C17 7.12/4)

That is not conditioned on the rounding mode in effect at any particular time.  Since MSVC does have an available `float` representation for infinity and `FLT_MAX` is required to be a representation of a *finite* number, it is non-conforming for `INFINITY` to evaluate equal to `FLT_MAX` in MSVC, under any circumstances.  Indeed, MSVC is non-conforming to whatever extent `INFINITY` ever fails to evaluate to a positive `float` infinity.

It is even more clear for `NAN`.  The specification says that it

> is defined if and only if the implementation supports quiet NaNs for the `float type`.

In that case,

> It expands to a constant expression of type `float` representing a quiet NaN.

(C17 7.12/5)

If `NAN` is defined at all then it expands to an expression that evaluates to a quiet NaN.  Period.  If MSVC provides for circumstances in which it instead expands to 0.0, then MSVC is non-conforming under those circumstances.

---

It should be acknowledged that most, if not all, C implementations have some non-conformity, whether by default or accessible via command-line options or similar.  Nevertheless, MSVC is notorious for its comparatively poor conformance among the widely used C implementations.

Comment: It seems that `((float)(_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF))` triggers underfunded behavior, because per C11, 6.3.1.5 Real floating types, 1: "If the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be represented, the behavior is undefined". Is that correct?

Comment: @pmor In the event that the `double` result of `_HUGE_ENUF * _HUGE_ENUF` is an infinity, I would say flatly no, because `float` can represent infinity.  In the event that the result is a finite value outside the range of `float` I would say that if you wrote that in your own source file then yes.  But you are not allowed to look under the covers in this sense to claim that *the implementation* has UB.  The expansion of `INFINITY` should be considered opaque -- the implementation is bound only with respect to the result of evaluating that expansion.

Comment: Thanks! Re: "opaque": exactly how I view it. Also: I'd expect that evaluation of `NAN` and `INFINITY` does not lead to raising of a floating-point exceptions. This is because with MSVC `f = NAN` or `f = INFINITY` can lead to raising of a floating-point exceptions. Which was totally unexpected by me, because logically: how writing to memory can cause raising of a floating-point exceptions? However, the C standard does not (as I understand) give the straight answer. Recently the CFP (C Floating Point) sub-group took attention to this subject. However, what is your opinion / view on this subject?

Comment: @pmor, I would find it surprising for evaluation of the expansion of `NAN` or `INFINITY` to, itself, cause an FP exception to be raised, but I don't think the current language specification forbids it.  I note in particular that it explicitly allows each to expand to a constant expression, from which it follows that there can be a runtime evaluation that produces the ultimate value.  From that, in turn, arises the possibility of an FP exception.  I account the actual production of an FP exception (or, preferably, lack thereof) as a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: Indeed, constant expressions are not required to be evaluated during translation. However, `float f = INFINITY;` placed at file scope is required to be successfully compiled, because a constant may be used in the initializer for object `f`, and, hence, a constant expression may be used in the initializer for object `f`. However, MSVC under `/std:c11 /Za /fp:strict` fails to compile it with `error C2099: initializer is not a constant`.

Comment: Re: "it is not a conformance requirement ...": can you elaborate? In C11, 4. Conformance, 6 there is "A conforming hosted implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program".

Comment: @pmor, I was actually thinking about section 5.2.4.1 and its "at least one" wording, but it looks like my claim was too strong.  I will shortly delete that and present a more conservative one.

Comment: @pmor, I find that particular failure an even more surprising than the previous.  Many compilers *intentionally* deviate from conformance under certain circumstances, but If MSVC accepts the same code with a different combination of options then I would construe the rejection you describe as arising from an incorrect interpretation of the language spec.